# Redmine in IronRuby

Tags: iis-7, redmine

I'd like to move my redmine installation to a Windows server. Since we're mostly a .NET shop it would be much easier for us if we could run redmine on IronRuby.

Has anybody tried this? What do I need to do to make it work?

**Update**

Just found [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/44334/how-do-i-serve-ruby-on-rails-applications-on-windows-server-2008/139867#139867) on a related SF question, posted back in May. IronRuby has been released recently. Anybody tried it yet?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Redmine is only supported on Ruby 1.8.6 and 1.8.7 and on Ruby Enterprise Edition. There are currently efforts ongoing to have Redmine running on jRuby and Rubinius. As there are not that many core devs running windows, I would not assume that anyone actively works on IronRuby compatibility.

If you are willing to help and code needed patches, you are welcome to speak up on http://redmine.org.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful reply. Unfortunately I don't have any time to invest in redmine right now.

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer on how I got it mostly working here...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783706/redmine-with-ironruby-windows

Hope this helps.